# SQL Merge one key row to make it stretch into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to format my rows better I have a primary I.D that repeats for every line. I want to instead of having that row repeat 3-8 times be one row that drags into the spaces pf each row that it is connected to.
example

in this case I have table called Colors
Kind is the primary I.D across these even if I have multiple tables involved,
select kind,
properties,
type,
numberOfProperties

from Colors

order by Kind

EDIT 09NOV2022:
I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 to write the query to the database, and I am outputting this information into a excel sheet as the final presentation of the data, I am trying to organize the query if possible to simply display the information in "Kind column" to basically show only once for the rows it is apart of. My apologies I didn't realize the errors and forgotten details.

| Kind | Properties | Type | numberOfProperties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
| Red | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |
| Yellow | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
| Yellow | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |
| Orange | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
| Orange | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |

Instead I want to display

| Kind | Properties | Type | numberOfProperties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
|  | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |
| Yellow | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
|  | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |
| Orange | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
|  | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |

Please let me know if this is possible, and how to do so Thank you!

Comment: Mysql or sql-server? They are not the same. Besides that, you should do that in your presentation layer, not in your data layer

Comment: If you just want to suppress the display of `Kind` when it is the same as the previous row, do that when you are rendering the rows (any language where you're looping and building HTML or what have you can keep track of the last `Kind` it saw, and only display when it's a new one). Also, do you have another column in the table that says Red comes before Yellow and Yellow comes before Orange? Knowing how you expect the order can help define which row is "first" for each Kind.

Comment: I am using SQL-Server my apoligies for the error, and by presentation what do you mean exactly? I am outputting this information into a excel sheet, does this refer to presentation in this case @nacho?

Comment: Yes, I have a column with basically a I.D number, that can be used to show which comes first, we can use "number of properties" in this instance. @Stuck at 1337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, if you just want to suppress the display of Kind when it is the same as the previous row, do that when you are rendering the rows. Any language where you're looping and building HTML or what have you can keep track of the last `Kind` it saw, and only display when it's a new one.

That said, you can do this in SQL Server, it's just not free. One way is to check the row number within each `Fruit_Number` and rank them by some other column (e.g. `numberOfProperties`). The `ORDER BY` is one column more complex than you might expect, in order to handle ties correctly.

```
SELECT Kind = CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
              (PARTITION BY Fruit_Number ORDER BY numberOfProperties)
              WHEN 1 THEN Kind ELSE '' END, 
       Properties,
       Type,
       numberOfProperties
  FROM #Colors
  ORDER BY Fruit_Number, Kind DESC, numberOfProperties;
```

Output:

| Kind | Properties | Type | numberOfProperties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
|  | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |
| Yellow | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
|  | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |
| Orange | sticky | Oil paint | 1 |
|  | messy | Oil Paint | 2 |

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IDwlkki0).